# Set theory proof

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Given a function $f: M \rightarrow N$ and a set of subsets $\Pi$ of $N$, then: 
 $\bigcup \left\{f^{-1}(P) |P\in\Pi\right\} = f^{-1}(\bigcup \Pi) = f^{-1}(\bigcup\left\{P|P\in \Pi\right\}).$

First off I am very new to writing formal proofs. I have some idea on what to do, but I can't think up exactly what I need to bring it full circle. My thoughts are that it will be two steps; first showing $\subseteq$ and then $\supseteq$. And to do this I figured I would let an element be in the original set and then show how it is also in the other set for each direction. But this is where I am lost, I can not think up how to show that this is true. Any help to get me in the right direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any function $f:M\to N$ and any set $A \subset N$,
$$
f^{-1}(A) = \{x \in M : f(x) \in A\}
$$
Write
$$
A = \bigcup_{P\in \Pi} P
$$
Let $x \in f^{-1}(A)$, then $f(x) \in A$. Hence, there exists $P \in \Pi$ such that
$$
f(x) \in P
$$
Thus, $x \in f^{-1}(P)$. Hence,
$$
x \in \bigcup_{P\in \Pi} f^{-1}(P)
$$
This is true for any $x\in f^{-1}(A)$, and hence
$$
f^{-1}(A) \subset \bigcup_{P\in \Pi} f^{-1}(P)
$$
Now can you try to prove the other containment using similar arguments?

Comment: Yes, this is what I needed. Thank you very much.